# Is it possible to preserve 'this' when calling a function in javascript via an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a jquery plugin that has an onSelect attribute. The user sets it to a function, and when that function is called, `this` refers to the object the plugin is applied to. All is good.

If I want to write a plugin that wraps this plugin, in order to inject some code into the onSelect, I do something like this:

```
// Get whatever the user put in
var extOnSelect = options['onSelect'];

// delete the onSelect attribute
delete options['onSelect'];

// re-add onSelect as an anonymous function that calls my method and the user's
var options = $.extend({ 
    'onSelect': function() { onSelect(); extOnSelect(); }
    }, options);

// call the plugin that I am wrapping / injecting extra onSelect code into
$(this).externalPlugin(options);
```

Then it will pass in my own onSelect code, while preserving what the user entered.

The only problem is, within each of those two functions `this` no longer refers to the object, it now refers to I think the generic inline function.

What's the best solution to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
extOnSelect.apply(this, arguments);
```

to call `extOnSelect` exactly like the current function.

You could use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but then you would need to pass the event object (and other possibe arguments) explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, what would 'arguments' refer to in this case?

Comment: `arguments` is an array-like object which contains the current arguments. In your case - the event handler - it would contain one item, the [jQuery] event object.

Comment: Worked great - the event handler actually triggers with some arguments and they're passed along nicely for me to use! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `call` method of javascript functions.

```
var options = $.extend({ 
'onSelect': function() { onSelect.call(this); extOnSelect.call(this); }
}, options);
```